# Javascript: Visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been working on the same problem and am now trying to use a different solution using visibility:hidden; visibility:visible; . The issue I am having is not making something visible or hidden, but rather combining two elements to play off each other. For example here is what I have:

```
<div id="external"></div>

<div>
<img src="../../images/labortab.png" style="float:left; width:38px; height:125px;" id="labor" onmousedown="document.external.visibility='false';document.external.visibility='true';"/>
<img src="../../images/odctab.png" style="float:left; width:38px; height:125px;" id="odc" onmousedown="document.external.visibility='true';document.external.visibility='false';"/> 
</div>
```

When I click on the first image or button, I want the external div to switch from its current state of visible to off and replace that div with another element already in the div that is hidden, switching this element to true and holding it there.

Then I want the second image or button to do the exact opposite switching the states from off to visible of the first element and then turning the 2nd element off. I am not good at writing JavaScript code and reading some of the solutions online are Greek to me. So if anyone understands what I'm trying to do would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried all sorts of codes, I can swap images in the div but I need to be able to switch an element (chart) and it doesn't want to recognize the element. As for codes, I've used getElementByID() and written everything in the DOM. I am not good at writing out the javascript function and that is probably what I need right now.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with jQuery if you are not using the library to bind the event handlers?

Comment: Do you want toggle some elements in external div?

Comment: I don't know how to bind them using jQuery. I have jQuery within the files but am unsure how to bind them if that is what I need to do.

Comment: Yes I have 2 buttons essentially, and I want each button to switch out a chart when clicked on that are both in the same div.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to toggle the visibility of the div based on a click event to one of the images. Try using the event `onclick` instead, and correctly reference the div's DOM properties:

`document.getElementById('external').style.visibility='hidden';`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eL2ak/) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using `style.display='hidden'` instead of the the visibility property. That would look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'hidden'
```

to hide

and

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block'
    //or inline or inline-block as needed
```

to show again.

Comment: Yeah this works except I need to make another element shown when I click on this to hide. Plus, I don't want the element be linked to only one script so you can turn this element on and off all the time. I need this to be linked to another button so that when you click on this, only the other button can unhide it, and vice versa.